# Implementing a type-safe service registry in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I would like to have a function that returns an object instance based on a given identifier (e.g. string or symbol). In code it would look maybe something like:

```
// define your services
type ServiceA = { foo: () => string };
const ServiceA = { foo: () => 'bar' };

type ServiceB = { bar: () => number };
const ServiceB = { bar: () => 1 };

// register your services with identifier
registry.register('serviceA', ServiceA);
registry.register('serviceB', ServiceB);

// get a service by its type identifier
// the important thing here: I want to know the type!
const serviceA: ServiceA = registry.get('serviceA');
serviceA.foo();
```

A further requirement: `ServiceA` and `ServiceB` do not share an interface or so, they can be totally different.

The challenge in the shown example is to know the exact type of the value returned by `registry.get`.

I tried an naive approach like:

```
enum ServiceType {
  A,
  B
}

const getService = (type: ServiceType): ServiceA | ServiceB => {
  switch (type) {
    case ServiceType.A:
      return ServiceA;
    case ServiceType.B:
      return ServiceB;
    default:
      throw new TypeError('Invalid type');
  }
};
```

and also the same thing with `if` but the compiler is not able to derive the concrete type of the returned value, when I execute `const x = getService(ServiceType.A);` the type of x is `ServiceA | ServiceB`, what I would like to see is `ServiceA`.

Is there any way to do something like this? If not, what is the reason for that from a compiler point of view?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you know in advance the type of services you will get back from your registry, then you can use a type representing a mapping from string keys to service types:

```
type ServiceMapping = {
  // first ServiceA is a string key, second is a type
  ServiceA: ServiceA;  
  // first ServiceB is a string key, second is a type
  ServiceB: ServiceB;
}

function getService<T extends keyof ServiceMapping>(type: T): ServiceMapping[T] {
  return ({
    ServiceA: ServiceA,
    ServiceB: ServiceB
  })[type];
}

// use it
const serviceA = getService('ServiceA'); 
serviceA.foo();  // works
```

---

If you want a registry you can keep adding things to and keep track of the types at compile time, you'll need to use a chain of registry objects.  You can't really use a constant registry object because TypeScript won't let you mutate the type of the object based on what you register.  But you can help TypeScript along by making the registry return a new *type* of object when you call its `register()` method, and you only hold onto the returned object.  Like this:

```
class ServiceRegistry<T> {  
  private constructor(private registry: T) {}
  register<K extends string, S>(key: K, service: S): ServiceRegistry<Record<K, S> & T> {    
    // add service to registry and return the same object with a narrowed type
    (this.registry as any)[key] = service;
    return this as any as ServiceRegistry<Record<K, S> & T>;
  }
  get<K extends keyof T>(key: K): T[K] {
    if (!(key in this.registry)) {
      throw new Error('Invalid type' + key);
    }
    return this.registry[key];
  }
  static init(): ServiceRegistry<{}> {
    return new ServiceRegistry({});
  }
}
```

So here's how you use it:

```
// register things
const registry = ServiceRegistry.init()
  .register('ServiceA', ServiceA)
  .register('ServiceB', ServiceB);
```

Note that the type of `registry` is the type of the return value of the last `register()` method, which has all the relevant mappings from type key to service object.

```
const serviceA = registry.get('ServiceA');
serviceA.foo(); // works
```

---

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=7&ts=4.2.3&ssl=10&ssc=1&pln=20&pc=1#code/PTAEBMFMDMEsDtKgJ4HsCuAnUBnSmA3WAY0hwCgAXZAByQGV8jSBBUAXlAG9RpVUAXKAAUASg4A+XJUwIA5qAC+AbnLFU8HJVCNCJSG048+gkePZSA5ACMAhpktLVVWgyb6AQh26g7mIWKSoPDoALbW+E5qGlo67qReRr72AeZSAIxR5PC2oWQ0tqQ6lLaUJACytjQ08tzk5KCg1HRxeqSV1bVGDY2tzAZCuv0sqr19noPxkB6jSj3Q6PDEZRqgcpCUQ-oAPAAqoJAAHpSQ8OA4oADWkGjQ4+1VNfByEsLNkEK7opNtkB1PcgA2rsALp1MaYDZYeAiLg9MZbVg-YYAGnhvUR02RnnRilEgPeINminqjXUmm0eF+hjWG0xwksmJYllEsypwwAdCYxMpGiBQAB3VCYS4UEn1HJ5HAFIoAdVglAAFixwOAFbAYuDQMQADa2HAXTEAJUgclgWkwyD2UjhYxosgIpSQ5It6GWwuE9tgjpOoEhZotyE+4h4JIhpvNJ0w2wA0gdjqdztJZM8UTpXtcg6AY2n2fpBt97pATQGZFaTepMOBY2n6FIAGSgXY29F8sC2VW4KZNVB+iOB0C2M59yjQpqKpA4XJIVDWABWkGWgoVisHwXsmFQAsg4CarlbIiV5o5-sjlsHFyHyHxmbBnDzpFm4dHmBhR8vl-gyAvRZLZ-Li7CtWObpqAjbNk+cxjOslCxvGJxnBcmaoHczbCJmQgxoWuyAjGYK2mMoCwHcwgAIToTcRFvoqx6noGoghgejRKpuArBJAbEAKKYJumAMgAkvAjo6rAu7vI4ADUVw3KyB5hoRkIvtRtH9mWgK3pB8mNFopQkFRCpiNipB-oG2xcIoLaESOY6IGxxqqZawjmbJYzyeKbZ9qWkRHs8FBkjE2h0WW3j2aWlocggBmiOiJ6qfgDJMpYtZTCw0VjLFXl8YyUweElRYeLJPQupSKXeEF4UwQlKUsmyKVcvwPKgPyQoihQ5CKEAA)

Comment: Perfect, the "static" solution is fine for me and exactly what i was looking for!

Comment: First solution work only in TS 3.3.333 :(

Answer (score 2):

I'm not really sure about your requirements but maybe you can use [overloads](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#overloads):

```
function getService(serviceName:"ServiceA"): typeof ServiceA;
function getService(serviceName:"ServiceB"): typeof ServiceB;
function getService(serviceName:string): object {
    switch(serviceName) {
        case "ServiceA":
            return ServiceA;
        case "ServiceB":
            return ServiceB;
        default:
            return null;
    }
}
```

---

Inspired by the [answer of jcalz](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47098963/4967497), you can alternatively use a JavaScript object as base for the registry:

```
const serviceMap = {
    "ServiceA": ServiceA,
    "ServiceB": ServiceB,
};

function getService<K extends keyof typeof serviceMap>(serviceName:K): typeof serviceMap[K] {
    return serviceMap[serviceName];
}
```

---

If you want to extend the service map in other modules, you can use a global interface. This is similar to what TypeScript itself uses for [`addEventListener`](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/065a996345fcfafd3c744d2a724a1ae9f31f9ab0/lib/lib.dom.d.ts#L6247) and maybe other functions.

```
declare global {
    interface ServiceMap {
        ["ServiceA"]: ServiceA,
        ["ServiceB"]: ServiceB,
    }
}

function getService<K extends keyof ServiceMap>(serviceName:K): ServiceMap[K] {
    // Get service somehow.
}
```

Other modules can than add additional services by extending the interface.

```
declare global {
    interface ServiceMap {
        ["ServiceC"]: ServiceC,
    }
}

// register service "ServiceC"
```

Comment: Woks as well but does not scale so nicely imo.

Comment: @BzumS Yea, you are right, but since it is a very simple solution, I wanted to list it here. I also added another suggestion inspired by the first suggestion [of jcalz](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47098963/4967497).